# How can I convert a WMF picture to GIF or PNG with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2009, gif, wmf

Is there a way to convert a [WMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) picture to [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) or [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) with the Delphi 2009 (or newer) run time libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PNG is not that hard, Delphi 2009 includes TPNGImage.
For GIF you can use GDI+ or the TGifImage component...

Here's the code :

```
procedure Test;
var
  p : TPicture;
  png : TPngImage;
begin
  try
    p := TPicture.Create;
    p.LoadFromFile('c:\INPUT.WMF');
    png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGB, 8, p.Width, p.Height);
    png.Canvas.Draw(0,0, p.Graphic);
    png.SaveToFile('C:\OUTPUT.png');
  finally
    Free(p);
    Free(png);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The variable p can also be declared with type TMetafile, this has the advantage that I can also use p.LoadFromStream.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, in general, to create the pngimage after p.width and p.height are initialized by loading input.wmf?  Of course this is just demo code.